# Receiving MMS by android application

Tags: java, android, xml, mms

I have to develop an android app which needs to receive MMS from a unique number. How can I make the app receive this MMS inside it and store it in the app rather than store it in the mobile Message box.

Note: the unique number is Mobile number for our server what shall I use? 
Do I need Array list to store the info. received from MMS or JSON, I'm really confused, can you explain please and thanks in advance..

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android